# Ubuntu 14.04: No longer connecting to wired connection

Tags: 14.04, internet, ethernet, ip, wired

I recently upgraded my system from 12.04 to 14.04 and everything was working fine.  However, one day it randomly stopped connecting to the wired connection.  My wireless connection works fine, but if I disable wireless and attempt to connect to the wired, it keeps attempting to obtain an ip address without avail.  When I run ifconfig, it shows no ip address for eth0.  Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure the cable is fine?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So for anyone using a "wired" connection that won't connect.  I just happened upon what seems to be a solution to my particular problem.  All i did was go to edit connections and add a new Ethernet connection and boom!  It worked fantastically.  At least for now...